# Log in firebase real-time database Activity

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

How can I make a Login activity to connect firebase?

I want to make an app that could login to firebase database project.

I want that someone that have project in firebase could connect his project. That why the login activity need to be dynamic and changeable, that anyone could login to his account without connecting the app to just one project.

For example - I built a desktop application in C# (on visual studio WinForm with FireSharp package), that has a login form to an exist real-time database project using the BasePath (the link of the ptoject), and the Secret in the setting.

Is this possible to do something like that on Android Studio?

Comment: Yup, that sounds possible. I recommend starting with the documentation on [getting started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start), [signing in with a pre-built UI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui) and or the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/) for Android devs.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Can you add more details? I'm a beginner in this thing. I've read what you sent but I didn't really understand this 

Comment: Since you're using Java, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAuthentication).